# Rxjs get distinct values of property value in array

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to get distinct values of a property in an observable array.

```
  let pt$ = Observable.of([{planTypeID : 1, description : 'test 1'}, 
                                {planTypeID : 2, description : 'test 2'}]);
    let planTypeIDs$ = pt$
        .flatMap(a => a)
        .map(a => a.planTypeID).distinct().toArray();
```

Is this the right way to do it in rxjs, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You could use `.from` instead of `.of`, that should spare you the `.flatMap`
2. [`distinct`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/distinct.html) will check the reference by default, so if you want to compare for contents you should create some kind of hash or make a custom comparer - but maybe that's not required here.

---

```
let pt$ = Observable.from([{planTypeID : 1, description : 'test 1'}, 
                            {planTypeID : 2, description : 'test 2'}]);
let planTypeIDs$ = pt$
    .map(a => a.planTypeID)
    .distinct()
    .toArray();
```

Comment: I am doing Observable.Of  to mimic the code that I have in my project. In the project I am working on, I have a service that  uses combinelatest to merge multiple observable array's and return a new array.

Comment: Okay - well it's difficult to optimize code that is not visible here ;-) - but then your current solution looks pretty much okay i guess