# finding distinct numbers from an array of numbers in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to TypeScripting and would like to know how to find distinct numbers from a array of numbers. Can I use the same functions as that in JavaScript in the filter function in Typescript or is there a different way. Thanks...

Comment: You can use the javascript function

Comment: Typescript is a wrapper around ALL javascript. You're only coding in javascript.

Comment: You could also leverage Observables for this as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41961982/rxjs-get-distinct-values-of-property-value-in-array

Comment: Thank you so much for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was able to work it out using js functions

Answer (score 0):

An old post but posting anyways, so that anyone seeking help might land here and use this solution.
So let's say we have a complex array and it has an element "OntheElementToDoDistinct" and we wish to get distinct values of it.

```
let distinctArray = array.filter((thing, i, arr) => {
return arr.indexOf(arr.find(t => t.OntheElementToDoDistinct === 
thing.OntheElementToDoDistinct )) === i;});
```